# Python - cannot set wallpaper with tempfile

Tags: python, python-3.5

**Code:**

```
import urllib.request
import tempfile
import shutil
import ctypes

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') as response, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, f)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, f.name, 0)
```

However, if you use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` it works.

The docs state:

> If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is
>   closed.

In my original code the file isn't deleted until after having exited the body of the `with` statement when it is automatically closed. So why isn't `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

To begin with, the value  of the `fWinIni` parameter needs to be changed:

```
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01
SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, f.name, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
```

This preserves the wallpaper after logging off.

Second, the temp file needs to be closed in order for `SystemParametersInfoW` to work. Therefore, `delete=False` is necessary.

Finally, delete the temp file manually using `os.remove(f.name)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the next couple sentences in the documentation, which read something like this:

> Under Unix, the directory entry for the file is either not created at all or
>   is removed immediately after the file is created. Other platforms do not
>   support this; your code should not rely on a temporary file created using
>   this function having or not having a visible name in the file system.